# ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '10' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: asynchronous, angular5, observable

I am getting an HTTP response and need to display the length of an array (the array is called 'Notifications'). I need to display "10" which is the length, but this is what I'm now displaying: [NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAnaX.png)

The error shown in my console: ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '10' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Please find my html code below:

```
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle dk" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-sm up bg-danger m-l-n-sm count" id="notcountbadge">{{cfNotificationsLength | async}}</span>
    </a>
```

and my ts code below:

```
public cfNotificationsLength: Observable<number>;
public cfNotifications: any;

ngOnInit() {
    console.log("HeaderBarComponent loaded successfuly!");

    this.referenceDataService.fetchNotifications(token)
        .subscribe((x: any) => {
            this.cfNotifications = x.Notifications;
            this.cfNotificationsLength = x.Notifications.length;
            console.log("cfNotifications", this.cfNotifications);
            console.log("cfNotificationsLength", this.cfNotificationsLength);
        },
            (err: any) => console.log("error", err)
        );

}
```

and my service below:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super(null);
}

public fetchNotifications(token: string): Observable<any> {
    //console.log("token in fetchNotifications", token);
    this.BASE_URL = window.location.origin;

    let fetchcfNotificationsCallResult = this.http
        .get(`${this.BASE_URL}` + `/` + token + `/api/Notifications`)
        .pipe(
            map((response: any) => <any>response)
        );

    return fetchcfNotificationsCallResult;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` pipe is used for Observables and is therefore not needed if you set the property by subscribing to the Observable. Just remove the pipe and it should work as expected.

**Edit**

Async pipe may be the way, try this:

```
public cfNotifications: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
    console.log("HeaderBarComponent loaded successfuly!");

    this.cfNotifications = this.referenceDataService
        .fetchNotifications(token)
        .map((x: any) => x.Notifications);
}
```

With the following html:

```
<span class="badge badge-sm up bg-danger m-l-n-sm count" id="notcountbadge">
    {{(cfNotifications | async)?.length}}
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I changed the declaration to 
public cfNotificationsLength: number; 
and removed the async pipe.
The error  has been removed, but I'm still displaying NaN as shown above.

Comment: @Giannis I see you're using `console.log` statements within your code, do you mind sharing what they say?

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code but I'm still getting the same (NaN)... Following your code I also tried in html {{cfNotificationsLength | async}}
and ts
 public cfNotificationsLength: Observable<any>;
this.cfNotificationsLength = this.referenceDataService
            .fetchNotifications(token)
            .map((x: any) => {
                x.Notifications.length
            });
but I'm still getting NaN...

Comment: Hopefully solved it. I did not change anything in my code except removing "count", as this was responsible for the "NaN" (it was trying to add 1 to undefined - length is undefined before the service gets back - and NaN was the result obviously...). I am now making the (+1) addition not inside the class using "count", but in my ts code after the service returns. The alternative solution is keeping the "count" as it is and add *ngIf="cfNotificationsLength !== undefined" inside span. Thank you once again for your help.